# Merge two list into a single keeping order without duplicate element

Tags: algorithm, list, merge

I have two list, I want to merge them together. Assume them as `list_left` and `list_right`
The merge rule is:

1. The two list has no duplicate element, and the merged result list has no duplicate element.
2. The order of elements in merged must be as same as in `list_left` and `list_right`.
3. If two elements (`e1`, `e2`) appear in both `list_left` and `list_right`, and the order of them is different in `list_left` and `list_right`. It must keep the order as them in `list_right`. In other words, if `e1` is before `e2` in `list_right`, `e1` must be before `e2` in merged list, no matter how about them in `list_left`.
4. If some elements are not mentioned in the three rules above, they can appear anywhere in the result merged list.

*some examples:*

```
list_left:   w  h  i  j  k 
list_right:  a  w  t  i  n
merged:      a  w  h  t  i  j  k  n


list_left:   w  h  i  j  k 
list_right:  j  w  m  n  a
merged:      j  w  h  i  k  m  n  a


list_left:   j  w  m  n  a
list_right:  w  h  i  j  k 
merged:      w  h  i  j  m  n  a  k


list_left:   a  b  c  d 
list_right:  e  f  g  h
merged:      a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

Have any methods to do with this problem?

Comment: If there are any questions, please @me, I will fix the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy elements from `list_left` that are not yet in `list_merged`. But when you see in `list_left` an element that is in `list_right` and not in `list_merged`, copy elements from `list_right` up to this element. When finished with `list_left`, copy what is remaining in `list_right`:

```py
list_left = "whijk"
list_right = "jwmna"
list_merged = ""
pos = 0

for x in list_left:
  if not x in list_merged:
    if x in list_right:
      xpos = list_right.index(x)
      list_merged += list_right[pos:xpos]
      pos = xpos + 1
    list_merged += x
list_merged += list_right[pos:]

print list_merged
```

To improve performance you could create a pair of sets and replace search in lists by search in these sets.

Comment: Not work when `list_left` = "obxyhruz", `list_right` = "ryz", the result must be "obxhryuz", not "obxryhuz".  Because, the order of 'h' and 'r' must be the same as `list_left`, according to rule 2.  The rule 3 only effects the conflict order of 'r' and 'y'

Comment: If I understand the rules correctly, rule 2 prescribes 'h' to be before 'r' and the same rule prescribes 'h' to be after 'y'. Also rule 3 requires 'r' before 'y'. Since all these conditions cannot be satisfied at the same time, we need to analyze in detail which rules are applicable here. There is no contradiction in rule 3. But what can rule 2 say about 'h'? It is just not applicable for 'h'. Which means the only working rule for 'h' is rule 4. And we could chose any place for 'h'.

Comment: As you said,  the only working rule for 'h' is rule 4. My mistake, I will modify the example in problem, and accept your answer.